# How can I include 2 php files variables?

Tags: php

i describe my question with example:

-index.php file content:

```
<?php
require_once(funcfile1.php);
include(funcfile2.php);
?>
<div><?php echo $var1; ?></div>
```

-funcfile1.php content:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'html codes'.$var2.'htmlcodes'.**[MY QUESTION]**.'other html or php cods'
?>
```

you see in index file echo $var1 that is in funfile1.php

but now i want add a variable for echo in [MY QUESTION] that this variable need funcfile2.php include

and funcfile2 just include in index.php

what can i do?

Comment: what you got when try your example

Comment: Can you show us your real code instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include the **funfile2.php**  into **funfile1.php**.
and when you will include the **funfile1.php** in index.php then **funfile2.php** file will also be include in index.php file.

-funcfile1.php content:

```
<?php
include(funcfile2.php);
$var1 = 'html codes'.$var2.'htmlcodes'.**[MY QUESTION]**.'other html or php cods'
?>
```

And index.php content will be:

```
<?php
require_once(funcfile1.php); 
// remove include funcfile1.php from here as it was includeed in funcfile1.php
?>
```